# playing with javascript function - object with naming and cloning

Tags: javascript, object

I stunbled on this through stackoverflow and it is a great resource and there is alot of conversation on this but i'm just still baffled why certain things dont work?

I studied c++ in college and sorta remember pointers

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index2.html

my problems are started in the code certain things aren't working

```
function theAdd(a, b){    
  return a*b;
} 

//creating a copy of the function
var add3 = new theAdd(); 

add3.name = 'nameProperty';
//alert( add3(1,2))   //why doesn't this work?  
alert(theAdd(5,5)  + " " +  theAdd.name);        


function Ball()    {
    return 'balltext';
}
var ball0=new Ball(); // ball0 now points to a new object

alert(  Ball()  );         // this works
alert(  ball0() );         // why doesn't this work? shouldn't it return balltext?
```

Comment: `ball0` is object, not a `function`. You cann't use operator `()` on it

Comment: Your first comment is completely wrong.  You need to learn what the `new` operator actually does.

Comment: This may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new  `new` does not do what you think it does.  It actually creates an instance of an object.

Comment: I find it funny when a function named `theAdd` performs multiplication ;)

Comment: `add3.name` sets the name for `add3` only.  Just that instance.  It doesn't modify `theAdd` at all.

Answer (score 3):

Because `ball0` is an object and you cannot use it like a function

Please check out this to see [how new works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> //creating a copy of the function
> var add3 = new theAdd();
> ```

This does **not** create a copy of the function. It calls the function as *constructor function*. `add3` will be the object that was created by that function.

> `alert( add3(1,2))`  why doesn't this work?

Because `add3` is not a function (it's a normal object).

> `alert(  Ball()  );` this works

You are calling the function the "normal" way. The result of the invocation will be the value the function returns.

> `alert(  ball0() );` why doesn't this work?

`ball0` is not a function.

> shouldn't it return balltext?

No. The `new` keyword invokes the function in a special way. From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> When the code new foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from `foo.prototype`.
> 2. The constructor function `foo` is called with the specified arguments and this bound to the newly created object. `new foo` is equivalent to `new foo()`, i.e. if no argument list is specified, foo is called without arguments.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. **If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead.** (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

Since you are not returning an object but a primitive value (a string in this case), the object that was created in the first step is returned and assigned to `ball0`.

When you are calling a function with `new` then your are using the function as *constructor function*, i.e. it is supposed to create a new object. The `new` operator ensures that an object will always be returned, no matter what the function itself returns.

Also have a look at:

- [MDN - Working with objects: Creating new objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects)
- [MDN - Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few questions there, but a lot of it relates to the concept of objects in JavaScript, and constructor functions. When you use the `new` operator, it creates an 'empty' object, and then calls the function with the object passed as the `this` parameter. Any function can be used as a constructor which I think is causing some of the confusion.

Going through some of the questions:

### Why doesn't `add3(1,2)` add the numbers?

This is because `add3` is an object, not a function, you used the new operator (and in this case, the constructor didn't do anything with `this`, its return value was ignored at construction time)

### alert(  Ball()  );

This is just a function call, like you would expect, it returns a string which is passed to `alert()`

### alert(  ball0() );

This doesn't do what you expect because ball0 is an object, using Ball as its constructor

[Heres](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) a pretty good primer for JavaScript objects over at W3Schools

Answer (score 1):

The line `var ball0 = new Ball();` is invoking the Ball method which returns a value of 'balltext', so the variable ball0 now has a value of 'balltext' which is a string, not a function.

Your last line of code `alert(ball0());` is attempting to call a function, which would work if ball0 was a reference to a function. Since the value of ball0 is a string this won't work. To pop open an alert that prints the value of the variable ball0 your code should read `alert(ball0);`

Hope this helps.